# xlsx pandas write to s3 (with tabs)

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, xlsx

I have a project where i need to write dataframes to xlsx in an s3 bucket. 
It's quite simple to load a file from s3 with pandas quite simply by:
    df= pd.read_excel('s3://path/file.xlsx')

But writing a file to s3 gives me problems.

```
 import pandas as pd

 # Create a Pandas dataframe from the data.
 df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('s3://path/', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 's3://path'
```

So how can i write xlsx files to s3 with pandas, preferably with tabs?

Answer (score 6):

```
import io
import boto3
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd

bucket = 'your-s3-bucketname'
filepath = 'path/to/your/file.format'
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

with io.BytesIO() as output:
    with pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
        df.to_excel(writer, 'sheet_name')
    data = output.getvalue()
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Bucket(bucket).put_object(Key=filepath, Body=data)
```

Comment: Thanks, this resolved a general "FileNotFoundError" error for me

Comment: Thanks! This did what pd.to_excel() did not accomplish. It kept throwing the FileNotFoundError. I am keeping this as a standard function from now on.